# Lexicon term description is showing special HTML characters

Tags: 7

I've installed the [Lexicon](http://drupal.org/project/lexicon) module so I can build a glossary. The problem I have is that the glossary terms description is showing special HTML characters (*see link*).

http://www.kalleload.net/uploads/jgoepbpqzfhh.jpg  *(screenshot)*

```
Lorum ispum "dolor > sit" amet!
```

will render as:

```
Lorum ispum &rsqou;dolor &gt; sit&rsqou; amet!
```

This problem only seems to occur when the term is linking to the Lexicon page.
I've been playing around with the settings, google'd the problem and went throught the module issue list, without any succes.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Thanks in advance,

Jeroen

Comment: Have you opened an issue in the Lexicon project?

Comment: I have created one just now.

Comment: I've figured it out. The module is using check_plain() on the title fields in which the description is stored. If you have the same issue as me you can remove it in the lexicon.module file. But be aware that this makes your site vulnerable for XSS.